# Can't decode text from byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I have a byte array,
that I am trying to turn into a string with no success. I have tried to decode it in many ways in c# :

```
 var stringToByte112 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
 var stringToByte11 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
 var stringToByte111 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
 var stringToByte1111 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
       = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
 var stringToByte11111 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
```

but to no sucsess.

The closest I was able to come to was this:

```
"\u0016\u0003\u0001\u0001\"\u0001\0\u0001\u001e\u0003\u0003A F?4Y'Y???\u0012}?\08?<SF?3B#??S?(?%?\0\0??0?,?(?$?\u0014?\n\0?\0?\0?\0?\0K\0J\0I\0H\09\08\07\06\0?\0?\0?\0??2?.?*?&?\u000f?\u0005\0?\0=\05\0??/?+?'?#?\u0013?\t\0?\0?\0?\0?\0G\0@\0?\0>\03\02\01\00\0?\0?\0?\0?\0E\0D\0C\0B?1?-?)?%?\u000e?\u0004\0?\0<\0/\0?\0A\0\a?\u0011?\a?\f?\u0002\0\u0005\0\u0004?\u0012?\b\0\u0016\0\u0013\0\u0010\0\r?\r?\u0003\0\n\0?\u0001\0\0I\0\v\0\u0004\u0003\0\u0001\u0002\0\n\0\u0010\0\u000e\0\u0017\0\u0019\0\u001c\0\u001b\0\u0018\0\u001a\0\u0016\0#\0\0\0\r\0 \0\u001e\u0006\u0001\u0006\u0002\u0006\u0003\u0005\u0001\u0005\u0002\u0005\u0003\u0004\u0001\u0004\u0002\u0004\u0003\u0003\u0001\u0003\u0002\u0003\u0003\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0003\0\u000f\0\u0001\u0001"
```

I also tried to get the encoding with this :

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(bytes),
                                                                          detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true))
                            {
                                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                enc = reader.CurrentEncoding; // the reader detects the encoding for you!
                            }
```

and this returned utf8 but the utf8 encoder returns gibberish.

The byte array in question :

```
"16-03-01-01-22-01-00-01-1E-03-03-99-38-BB-63-4E-10-BB-9D-8A-1D-55-33-5C-29-1B-83-D2-40-76-57-1D-58-95-28-28-37-F0-4F-E8-4C-0E-6C-00-00-AC-C0-30-C0-2C-C0-28-C0-24-C0-14-C0-0A-00-A5-00-A3-00-A1-00-9F-00-6B-00-6A-00-69-00-68-00-39-00-38-00-37-00-36-00-88-00-87-00-86-00-85-C0-32-C0-2E-C0-2A-C0-26-C0-0F-C0-05-00-9D-00-3D-00-35-00-84-C0-2F-C0-2B-C0-27-C0-23-C0-13-C0-09-00-A4-00-A2-00-A0-00-9E-00-67-00-40-00-3F-00-3E-00-33-00-32-00-31-00-30-00-9A-00-99-00-98-00-97-00-45-00-44-00-43-00-42-C0-31-C0-2D-C0-29-C0-25-C0-0E-C0-04-00-9C-00-3C-00-2F-00-96-00-41-00-07-C0-11-C0-07-C0-0C-C0-02-00-05-00-04-C0-12-C0-08-00-16-00-13-00-10-00-0D-C0-0D-C0-03-00-0A-00-FF-01-00-00-49-00-0B-00-04-03-00-01-02-00-0A-00-10-00-0E-00-17-00-19-00-1C-00-1B-00-18-00-1A-00-16-00-23-00-00-00-0D-00-20-00-1E-06-01-06-02-06-03-05-01-05-02-05-03-04-01-04-02-04-03-03-01-03-02-03-03-02-01-02-02-02-03-00-0F-00-01-01"
```

No really sure where to go from here,
does anyone have an idea what encoding this is and how to get something "normal" looking?

link to file with all bytes saved to txt file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/14orWRM5LunbJOgPYQ5wbhxvwG-AFZ1SM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There seem to be \0 bytes, so it doesn't seem to be _one_ string (if there is one in the first place). What exactly and exhaustively do you know about the byte array? Where does it come from? What is the source likely to be using? Are you 100% positively _sure_ you _can_ expect a string?

Comment: Is the original byte array confidential or are you free to post it?

Comment: The byte array comes from an outside vendor, sending a TCP event, that should hold info for the event in question. Added more info in the question.

Comment: Have you tried to write it to a file as-is and have a look with a Hex-Editor?

Comment: Looking into it, never used it before.

Comment: Post a link to the binary file.

Comment: I am wondering if this is any string at all. Is there any accompanying documentation which describes what to do with the data?

Comment: No docs and the vendor is not available its a legacy software so pretty much on my own here,

Comment: If this is not some super fancy codepage, I am very afraid it could in fact be binary data, not text. And the more legacy it is, the more this is probably the case.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I was able to contact the vendor and there was a bug on their side, the bytes are nonsense.